# What are the default events fired for mousedown on a span?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a span nested within several divs (nothing else special about the DOM) and on mousedown I'm running `e.preventDefault()` in order to prevent text selection from happening. I don't want to stop the span element from being focused on because I want to allow subsequent keydown events on it. I'm guessing the best way to do this would be to manually trigger events that I want from the list of default events that I'm preventing (though I'm open to other thoughts).

My question is, when I run `e.preventDefault()`, what things would naturally trigger? Or in other words, what things am I preventing?

Comment: Any reason not to use the [`user-select` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) ?

Comment: @Seblor didn't even think of that. I'll toy with that and make sure that fits my needs. Still curious about all the events that fire but this is really helpful.